# Want to add Controls at Runtime in IPhone Application C#, Monotouch

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios

I have a TabViewController. It consists of several views. For a particular view I want to add some buttons dynamically at runtime. The view already have some controls which has been created using Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add controls like this:

```
    // create new control
    var control = new UIView(); // or UIButton, etc.

    // set control props ..
    control.Hidden = false;
    control.Frame = x // = Bounds
    // ...

    // add control to parent
    window.AddSubview(control);
```

Comment: `UIButton b=new UIButton(new RectangleF(102f,440f,10f,100f)); b.SetTitle("Value",UIControlState.Normal); b.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black,UIControlState.Normal); b.Hidden=false; Item3View.SetNativeField("value" ,b); Item3View.Add(b);`
 This code not worked –

Answer (score 0):

just sample code for UIButton

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[yourView addSubview:button];
```

Here you can set Button Type/Controlling Event/Title etc as per your requirement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `UIButton b=new UIButton(new RectangleF(102f,440f,10f,100f));
    b.SetTitle("Value",UIControlState.Normal);
    b.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black,UIControlState.Normal);
    b.Hidden=false;
    Item3View.SetNativeField("value" ,b);
    Item3View.Add(b);`

This code not worked

Comment: I believe this code is not available in answer. Where did you get this code ? Have you tried with the code I have given above ?

Comment: This I have tried by my own. as I am using C# thus I used this. the code what you have given I believe that was in Objective C.

Comment: var button = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect); button.frame = new RectangleF(100f, 100f, 100f, 100f); button.SetTitle("click me", UIControlState.Normal); Item3View.Add(button); I hope this works for you.

Comment: Yes, Its worked.. Thanks you. So we have to declare it using "var". Another problem in my code was the Frame positions. Thanks a lot..

Comment: Glad it worked for you. If the answer was useful you should accept it using the √ symbol to its left. Thanks.